# Add a " ' " around any number of functions in a formula/string

Tags: r, string, formula

**The Simple Request:**

I'd like to take formulas/strings similar to the following:

```
"A ~ 1 + B + C + L(diff(B), -k:k) + L(diff(C), -k:k)"
```

and change them to treat functions as character as follows:

```
"A ~ 1 + B + C + `L(diff(B), -k:k)` + `L(diff(C), -k:k)`"
```

There may be any number of "L(diff(___), -____:____)" in a string.

**The Background:**

This is so that I may take the output models made with dynlm and run them with functions that rely on "lm" objects only.

```
# package
library(dynlm)
# data
A <- as.ts(rnorm(20, 10, 2))
B <- as.ts(A + rnorm(20, 6, 2))
C <- as.ts(rnorm(20, 3, 1))
# lags/leads
k <- 1

# dynlm model
dyn.mod <- dynlm(A ~ 1 + B + C + L(diff(B), -k:k) + L(diff(C), -k:k))

# capture the formula and data
dyn.mod.call <- gsub("    ", "", paste(deparse(dyn.mod$call$formula), collapse = "")) # just in case formula is too long
dyn.mod.model <- dyn.mod$model # the matrix that was created from  the call formula

# Do the following
lm(dyn.mod.call, data = dyn.mod.model) # Will not run obviously, 
lm(A ~ 1 + B + C + `L(diff(B), -k:k)` + `L(diff(C), -k:k)`, data = dyn.mod.model) # will run 

# how do I change
dyn.mod.call
# [1] "A ~ 1 + B + C + L(diff(B), -k:k) + L(diff(C), -k:k)"

# to ad " ` " around each dynlm "L()" function so the process is not manual?
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can I ask why the downvote? I thought this was a useful question with runnable code provided?

Comment: Don't edit your question to include your accepted answer. You do that by clicking the check box next to the answer you accept. The community decides which answer they like best by voting. (This this is unrelated to the downvote)

Comment: I appreciate the notice and will do so in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that we don't really want to replace all function calls since `+` is a function (and even `~` can be regarded as a function) but we only want to replace just certain ones. Suppose that the only function call that we want to process is `L`.  Modify the second `if` appropriately according to what it is that is to be matched.  The function shown works recursively. No packages are used.

```
enquote_L <- function(x) {
    if (length(x) == 1) return(x)
    if (x[[1]] == as.name("L")) return(as.name(format(x)))
    replace(x, -1, lapply(x[-1], enquote_L))
  }

s <- "A ~ 1 + B + C + L(diff(B), -k:k) + L(diff(C), -k:k)"
enquote_L(as.formula(s))
## A ~ 1 + B + C + `L(diff(B), -k:k)` + `L(diff(C), -k:k)`
```

**ADDED**

If there were a variety of functions and `+` and `~` were the only ones not to be processed then a variation might be to replace the second `if` with:

```
if (x[[1]] != as.name("+") && x[[1]] != as.name("~")) return(as.name(format(x)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use string manipulation to change the formula.

```
x <- deparse(A ~ 1 + B + C + L(diff(B), -k:k) + L(diff(C), -k:k))
parts <- unlist(strsplit(x, " \\+ "))
parts <- c(parts[1:3], paste0("`", parts[4:5], "`"))
as.formula(paste(parts, collapse = " + "))
```

Comment: Troh, thank you for this. I edited the bottom of my post based on what you wrote and am wondering how to dynamically select the "L(" parts of x using grep, as opposed to simply "L"? Thanks for your input!

Comment: `grep("L\\(", parts)` The \\ will negate the special character and pass it in as `(`.